# Table of absolute magnitudes of stars by spectral type and photometric band

Tags: absolute-magnitude

I would like to find a table where I can, say, look for K5 dwarfs and read off that stars of that type have on average an absolute magnitude of X.XX in the infrared L band and Y.YY in the G band. I've looked everywhere and I can't find a compilation of this kind of information. Does any such thing exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of standard papers containing the table you want.

Kenyon & Hartmann (1995) http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1995ApJS..101..117K

Table A5 contains many colours for stars as a function of spectral type. You need to combine this with something that gives absolute V magnitude along the main sequence, like that of [Schmidt-Kaler (1982)](https://materials.springer.com/lb/docs/sm_lbs_978-3-540-31378-6_1).

An alternative, that has colours for both main sequence and pre main sequence stars (though the absolute magnitude of a PMS star is age-dependent) is found in Pecaut & Mamajek (2013).
 http://arxiv.org/abs/1307.2657

Online table at
 http://vizier.cfa.harvard.edu/viz-bin/VizieR-3?-source=J/ApJS/208/9/table5

Comment: Perfect, thanks! The Kenyon & Hartmann paper is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of stars [citation needed] and they are organised into catalogs by various organisations, well known catalogs include the [UNSO catalog](http://www.usno.navy.mil/USNO/astrometry/optical-IR-prod/icas) (produced by the united states Naval office) and the Guide Star Catalog (used by Hubble to accurately posistion itself)

I think the best for you is the Hipparcos catalog of stars, as it can be browsed quite easily by spectral type.

[HEASARC Browse (Catalog search)](https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/db-perl/W3Browse/w3table.pl?tablehead=name%3Dhipparcos&Action=More%20Options)